# What should I do when I feel the urge to use object-style polymorphic messaging in Haskell?

Tags: c#, haskell, polymorphism, constants

I have a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026038/strongly-typed-events-in-haskell). What's the idiomatic Haskell equivalent to a polymorphic class-level constant in an object-oriented language?

---

I'm experimenting with event-sourcing, using [Event Store](http://geteventstore.com/) and Haskell. I've got stuck trying to figure out the logic that saves and loads events.

Event Store is based on the concept of *event streams*; in an object-oriented domain model there's normally a 1:1 relation between event streams and aggregates. You can organise the streams into *categories*; typically you'll have one category per aggregate class in your domain model. Here's a sketch of how you might model it in C#:

```
interface IEventStream<T> where T : Event
{
    string Category { get; }
    string StreamName { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Events { get; }
}

class PlayerEventStream : IEventStream<PlayerEvent>
{
    public string Category { get { return "Player"; } }
    public string StreamName { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<PlayerEvent> Events { get; private set; }
    public PlayerEventStream(int aggregateId)
    {
        StreamName = Category + "-" + aggregateId;
    }
}

class GameEventStream : IEventStream<GameEvent>
{
    public string Category { get { return "Game"; } }
    public string StreamName { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<GameEvent> Events { get; private set; }
    public GameEventStream(int aggregateId)
    {
        StreamName = Category + "-" + aggregateId;
    }
}

class EventStreamSaver
{
    public void Save(IEventStream stream)
    {
        CreateStream(stream.StreamName);
        AddToCategory(stream.StreamName, stream.Category);
        SaveEvents(stream.StreamName, stream.Events);
    }
}
```

This code ensures a `GameEvent` never gets sent to a Player's event stream and vice versa, and that all the categories are correctly assigned. I'm using polymorphic constants for `Category` to help protect this invariant, and to make it easy to add new stream types later.

Here's my first attempt at translating this structure into Haskell:

```
data EventStream e = EventStream AggregateID [e]

streamName :: Event e => EventStream e -> String
streamName (EventStream aggregateID (e:events)) = (eventCategory e) ++ '-':(toString aggregateID)

class Event e where
    eventCategory :: e -> String
    -- and some other functions related to serialisation

instance Event PlayerEvent where
    eventCategory _ = "Player"

instance Event GameEvent where
    eventCategory _ = "Game"

saveEventStream :: Event e => EventStream e -> IO ()
saveEventStream stream@(EventStream id events) =
    let name = streamName stream
        category = eventCategory $ head events
    in do
        createStream name
        addToCategory name category
        saveEvents name events
```

This is pretty ugly. The type system requires `eventCategory` to mention `e` somewhere in its signature, even though it's not used anywhere in the function. It'll also fail if the stream contains no events (because I'm trying to attach the category to the type of events).

I'm aware that I'm trying to write C# in Haskell - is there a nicer way to implement polymorphic constants of this type?

---

**Update**: As requested, here are the type signatures that I think the (presently unimplemented) stubs in the `do` block should have:

```
type StreamName = String
type CategoryName = String

createStream :: StreamName -> IO ()
addToCategory :: StreamName -> CategoryName -> IO ()
saveEvents :: Event e => StreamName -> [e] -> IO ()
```

These functions would be responsible for communicating with the database - setting up the schema and serialising out the events.

Comment: Are you wanting a heterogeneous list (or other data structure) of `Event e => e`?  If you're trying to implement this with Haskell type classes, then you're going about it the wrong way.  You can "fake" it with existentially quantified types, but those aren't the recommended way to do it.

Comment: @bheklilr My data structures are as per my previous question: `data PlayerEvent = PlayerCreated Name | NameUpdated Name`. An event stream representing a Player aggregate would then be an `EventStream PlayerEvent`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - BURN! In fact I'm working on a pet project myself, so I think I'm entitled to use someone else's pet project ;)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Your comment has been flagged as not constructive.  Haskell is certainly not an "academic pet project", and SO is not the place to start flame wars over languages and what they should be used for.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson What are the types of `createStream`, `addToCategory`, and `saveEvents`?  Since they're not defined yet, what do _you_ think they types should be?  Often in Haskell it's advantageous to figure out the types with `myFunc :: <Type Signature>; myFunc = undefined`, get it to compile, then start implementing the functionality.

Comment: @bheklilr I just stubbed them out to make the question read fluently. I don't think they're directly relevant to the question. And since I'm still learning about Event Store, I might have got the steps completely wrong ;). But anyway, see my edit for the type signatures I'm imagining for those actions.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson If I understand, you might want to have either a sum type that determines the "kind" of event (i.e. Player or Game) and then you can have a function that gives the appropriate string based on that like this: `data EventType = PlayerEvent | GameEvent`. Another possibility would be to have it as a field in an `Event` type like this: `data Event = Event { eventType :: String, ... }`. Also, shouldn't `createStream` have a type more like `StreamName -> IO EventStream`?

Comment: @DavidYoung I did consider introducing a new `EventType` type. The problem is that the compiler can't stop you from creating an `EventStream` with an `EventType` of `PlayerEvent` and then filling it with events related to the `Game` aggregate! That's why I introduced the `PlayerEvent` and `GameEvent` types in the first place. (See my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026038/strongly-typed-events-in-haskell) for more on this decision.)

Comment: @bheklilr thank god the OP has a sense of humor, don't be too defensive about Haskell please.

Comment: Try an existential, just to get a feel for what OO encoding looks like.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the question. it would be nice to rephrase the question in hindsight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people suggest existential types, but unless I am grossly misunderstanding, you want to limit certain even streams to certain types.

Well first of all,

```
data EventStream e = EventStream AggregateID [e]

streamName :: Event e => EventStream e -> String
streamName (EventStream aggregateID (e:events)) = (eventCategory e) ++ '-':(toString aggregateID)
```

Should seem strange. You call `eventCategory` on the first even and throw away the rest, so you assume the category of all the events is the same. But of course, the `eventCategory` can return different strings for different values of an event. And if there are no events, you have to do `eventCategory undefined`.

One idea is to change the type of `eventCategory`:

```
data Proxy p = Proxy 

class Event e where
    eventCategory :: Proxy e -> String
```

Now it is impossible for the function to return different strings for different values of the event, because it has no access to an actual value. In other words, `eventCategory` depends only on the type, not the value.

Another possibility is to follow the c# code, namely, category is a property of a stream, not an event:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.ByteString 

class Event e where 
  deserialize :: ByteString -> e 
  ... other stuff

class Event e => EventStream t e where 
  category :: t e -> String
  aggregateId :: t e -> Int 
  events :: t e -> [e] 
  name :: t e -> String 
  name s = category s ++ "-" ++ show (aggregateId s)
```

The `EventStream` typeclass corresponds closely with the interface.

Notice how `name` is inside the typeclass, but you can write it without knowing *which* instance you are using. You could just as easily move it out of the typeclass, but an implementation may decide it will define a custom name, which would override the default defintion.

Then you define your events:

```
data PlayerEvent = ...
instance Event PlayerEvent where ...

data GameEvent = ...
instance Event GameEvent where ...
```

Now the stream types:

```
data PlayerEventStream e = PES Int [e] 
instance EventStream PlayerEventStream PlayerEvent where 
  category = const "Player" 
  aggregateId (PES n _) = n
  events (PES _ e) = e 

data GameEventStream e = GES Int [e] 
instance EventStream GameEventStream GameEvent where 
  category = const "Game" 
  aggregateId (GES n _) = n
  events (GES _ e) = e
```

Notice the event types are isomorphic, but still distinct types. You can't have `PlayerEvent`s in a `GameEventStream` (or rather, you can, but there is no `EventStream` instance for a `GameEventStream` containing `PlayerEvent`s). You can even strengthen this relation:

```
class Event e => EventStream t e | t -> e where
```

This says that for a given stream type, only one event type may exist, so defining two instances like so is a type error :

```
instance EventStream PlayerEventStream PlayerEvent where 
instance EventStream PlayerEventStream GameEvent where
```

The save function is trivial:

```
saveEventStream :: EventStream t e => t e -> IO ()
saveEventStream s = do 
  createStream (name s)
  addToCategory (name s) (category s) 
  saveEvents (name s) (events s)
```

I have no idea if this is what you are actually looking for but it seems to accomplish the same things as the c# code.

Comment: This seems perfect! It looks like `class Event e => EventStream t e | t -> e` is the key - could you explain in a little more detail what it means/how it works?

Comment: The part after the pipe `t -> e` is called a functional dependency. They have many uses, but here it is used to say that the event type `e` is determined uniquely by the stream type `t`. With the functional dependancy, if you write `events (PES 0 [])` then the compiler knows the type of the output is `PlayerEvent`, even though `[]` is fully polymorphic .

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to show you how this might be done without using type classes. I often find that the results are simpler.

First, here are a few guesses at what types you might be using. You provided some of these:

```
type CategoryName = String
type Name = String
type PlayerID = Int
type StreamName = String
data Move = Left | Right | Wait

data PlayerEvent = PlayerCreated Name | NameUpdated Name
data GameEvent = GameStarted PlayerID PlayerID | MoveMade PlayerID Move
```

Record types are often a useful replacement for classes. In this example `e` will either be a `GameEvent` or a `PlayerEvent`.

```
data EventStream e = EventStream
    { category :: String
    , name :: String
    , events :: [e]
    }
```

In C# you had subclasses which override the `Category` property. in Haskell you can use smart constructors for this purpose. If your C# subclasses were overriding methods, then in Haskell you would include functions within the `EventStream e` type. Other modules in your program can be prevented from creating invalid `EventStream` objects by only exposing these smart constructors:

```
-- generalized smart constructor
mkEventStream :: CategoryName -> Int -> EventStream e
mkEventStream cat ident = EventStream cat (cat ++ " - " ++ show ident) []

playerEventStream :: Int -> EventStream PlayerEvent
playerEventStream = mkEventStream "Player"

gameEventStream :: Int -> EventStream GameEvent
gameEventStream = mkEventStream "Game"
```

Finally, you have defined a few functions. Here's how they might be written:

```
createStream :: StreamName -> IO ()
createStream = undefined

addToCategory :: StreamName -> CategoryName -> IO ()
addToCategory = undefined

saveEvents :: EventStream e -> IO ()
saveEvents = undefined

saveEventStream :: EventStream e -> IO ()
saveEventStream stream = do
    createStream name'
    addToCategory name' (category stream)
    saveEvents stream
  where
    name' = name stream
```

This is closer to what your C# example does. The stream's name is fixed when created, and the category is part of each stream rather than linked to the type of each element.

Comment: This does seem much simpler, but how can you prevent clients from creating an `EventStream PlayerEvent` with a category of `"game"`?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read your answer properly - you only export the smart constructors, obviously. So a "smart constructor" is kind-of like a factory method?

Comment: I'm not sure. In OO, aren't factory methods used with inheritance? As in, some block of code calls methods of a parent class to create objects which at runtime end up being instances of a child class?

Comment: Yes, your modules enforce legitimate instances of the `e` in `EventStream e` by only exporting the smart constructors; not the data constructors. Another benefit to doing things this way is that you can have several smart constructors which all create the same type. With type classes you're limited to a single instance per type.

Comment: Factory methods have a bunch of different uses. They're basically about creating an object when the instantiation logic is too complex for a simple constructor. This can include cases where you need a subclass but don't know which one you need. Things get complex when you subclass the factory itself :)

Comment: Data constructors in haskell (ie: `PlayerCreated`) don't allow for any logic, so I suppose a haskell "smart constructor" would map to a C# class constructor. Perhaps `mkEventStream` above could be considered a factory method since it doesn't know which type to put in place of `e`. That is to say, the `e` in `mkEventStream`'s return value is determined by the caller.